# How to copy TD table values from jQuery to TextBoxFor MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to copy the results from a jQuery table and pass it to TextBoxBox.
I have seen examples of how to copy TextBox to TextBox but in this case I require the Jquery table to TextBox

jQuery Table:

```
                    function loadData(data) {
                        // Here we will format & load/show data 
                        var tab = $('<table class="myTable"></table>');
                        var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
                        thead.append('<th>Department</th>').css({ "text-align": "center" });
                        thead.append('<th>Email</th>').css({ "text-align": "center" });
                        thead.append('<th>Employee Name</th>').css({ "text-align": "center" });
                        thead.append('<th>Employee Number</th>').css({ "text-align": "center" });
                        thead.append('<th>Team Leader</th>').css({ "text-align": "center" });
                        thead.append('<th>Team</th>').css({ "text-align": "center" });

                        tab.append(thead);
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            // Append database data here
                            var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
                            trow.append('<td>' + val.DEPT_CD + '</td>');
                            trow.append('<td>' + val.EMAIL + '</td>');
                            trow.append('<td>' + val.EMPNAME + '</td>');
                            trow.append('<td>' + val.EMPNO + '</td>');
                            trow.append('<td>' + val.MGR_EMAIL + '</td>');
                            trow.append('<td>' + val.TEAM + '</td>');
                            tab.append(trow);
                        });
                        $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
                        $("#UpdatePanel").html(tab);
                    };
```

Here is the TextBoxFor that I need to put those results.

```
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b[m].REQUESTOR_EMPNAME, new { id = "empname" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b[m].REQUESTOR_EMPNO, new { id = "emp" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b[m].DEPT_CD, new { id = "dept" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b[m].ORG_NAME, new { id = "team" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b[m].EMAIL_ID, new { id = "email" })</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b[m].APPROVER1, new { id = "mgr" })</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi where are these textbox located in same table ? Also there are separate textboxes for each rows which you appending ?

Comment: They are 2 different tables but I require the results of the first table to be placed in the textboxes of the second table

Comment: It should assign value on click of something and also for each row there is same row in another table with textboxes ?